# AmCharts v3 stop old charts building from up

Tags: amcharts

I have an angular app that utilizes AmCharts v3. If I render a new chart I can access it from the console using `AmCharts.charts` - If I then navigate to another page and render a new chart, calling `AmCharts.charts` now has 2 charts. This will continue every new chart rendered is added to the AmCharts main object, it just keeps getting larger. Does AmCharts offer a way to "clean up" old charts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `clear` on the [chart instance](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#clear) (e.g. `chartInstance.clear()`) before you render your next chart. `clear` is also available on the [AmCharts object](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#clear) if you need to clear all chart instances (`AmCharts.clear()`).